# Safari IOS keeps redirecting to https to non-supported http site

Tags: ios, safari

I'm using Cloudflare, i have set redirect https to http and it just ends up in a redirect loop on Safari,
 Neither removing cache worked. Its very annoying , for a service status page of my web.

But what, it works on Chrome, Puffin and a lot of other thirdy parties browsers..

Safari just tries to redirect HTTP to HTTPS.

Is there any way to stop this?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem too and posted my solution on the Apple community site:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250107953